# creating Skrollr elements dynamically, scroll fails

Tags: javascript, parallax, skrollr

I hard coded a Skrollr demo page and it worked great. Hard coding the data tags is tedious so I went with creating the img divs dynamically. But now I can't get it to work!
I need another set of eyes to look at my code. I'm sure I am overlooking something simple.
Ideally when you scroll down the images should appear to animate (by having their visibility toggled) but the div should stay at a  fixed position on the page.
http://moto.oakley.com

has a good example of Skrollr in action.

Here is a sample of the img div before the JS runs

```
<img data--10000-top="display:block;" data-1-top="display:none;" data-anchor-target="#bps_ux" data-src="images/bps/bps0001.jpg" src="images/bps/bps0001.jpg" class="frame preload skrollable skrollable-after" style="display: block;" alt="" >
```

Then I have a JS function with a for loop that appends to the img div and incrementing the data tags by 20. I think my use of data-- is not quite right.

Once the JS runs the div looks like this but with 75 images.

```
<img class="frame preload" src="images/bps/bps0001.jpg" data-src="images/bps/bps0001.jpg" data-anchor-target="#bps_ux" data-20-top="display:block;" data-0-top="display:none;" alt="bpsSprite frame 0001">
<img class="frame preload" src="images/bps/bps0002.jpg" data-src="images/bps/bps0002.jpg" data-anchor-target="#bps_ux" data-1-top="display:none;" data--0-top="display:block;" data--20-top="display:none;" alt="bpsSprite frame 0002">
<img class="frame preload" src="images/bps/bps0003.jpg" data-src="images/bps/bps0003.jpg" data-anchor-target="#bps_ux" data-1-top="display:none;" data--20-top="display:block;" data--40-top="display:none;" alt="bpsSprite frame 0003">
```

Here is my test link with the full code
http://retropunk.com/files/bps-skrollr/

Thanks for any tips
- P

Comment: Please show your code in the question (not a link to a site with the code), and tell us why it's not working and what it's expected to do.

Comment: @Syon ok, I updated the question to be more clear. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skrollr doesn't know about your dynamic elements. Two options

1. Switch the order of the two last script tags (call `init` **after** the images have been created)
2. Call `s.refresh()` after adding the images.

Comment: I didn't even reaize that I was initializing Skrollr before the image load! DOH! Dynamic script is working like a charm now! Awesome!